# 403 Laravel Auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Why does a 403 error occur when I log in and am forwarded to a route? However, if I enter the URL manually, the URL will be accessible

This is a middleware role with identification 1, it should be accessible with user role 1

here is the code

php artisan route:clear && php artisan route:cache
composer dump-autoload

is not working ,

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $this->validate($request, [
            'identifier' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        $credentials = [
            'password' => $input['password']
        ];

        if (strpos($input['identifier'], '@') !== false) {
            $credentials['email'] = $input['identifier'];
        } else {
            $credentials['username'] = $input['identifier'];
        }

        if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            if (auth()->user()->role === 1) {
                return redirect()->route('seller.dashboard');
            } else {
                abort(403, 'Anda tidak memiliki akses.');
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('seller.login')->with('error', 'Email atau Password tidak sesuai.');
        }
    }
```

It should be directly forwarded to route('seller.dashboard') without a 403 statement because the person logging in is role 1

Comment: can you please provide route and middleware code?

Comment: try using auth->validate($credentials); first and then attempt($credentials) when user role = 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### The auth attempt method not working properly try to troubleshoot the the attempt method.

```
auth()->attempt($credentials)
```

> check this line what is returning ?

```
dd(auth()->attempt($credentials));
```

> if auth attempt return true then check the auth of user. which user is authenticated?

```
dd(auth()->user());
```

> here you can achive you answer if user authenticated what is the role and if not
> so try to resolve the auth attempt.